# Odd Php Session Behavior

Tags: php, session

I'm having some issues with session for some reason. I've never had issues with sessions, up until now. I have three pages:

```
/index.php
/test/sessions.php
/test/sessions2.php
```

All of which have the same code(/test/sessions.php also sets a session value):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo(session_id());
?>
```

session.php(setting value):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
?>
```

The code works fine on the pages in the /test/ directory, but not on the index page. When I navigate to the index page it will clear all session data, but like I said, noting is wrong with the pages in the /text/ directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: Clear what session data? You aren't setting any session data in this code.

Comment: @GoogleGuy "All of which have the same code(/test/sessions.php also sets a session value):"

Comment: In other words the code you're showing here doesn't actually reflect the code that's causing the problem? That's good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [session cookie path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) seems to be `/test` `.` or `./`. Setting it to `/` would fix this probably.

Comment: session.cookie_path = "/" in my php.ini did not fox the issue.

Comment: php.ini can be overridden plenty. What does `phpinfo()` in `./test/sessions.php` say about session cookie params?

Comment: Directive = session.cookie_path Local Value = / Master Value = /

Comment: Hm, damn, I was 99% sure this was it, because other reasons are... obscure. You het the exact same values for both ./index.php & ./test/*.php scripts? Then I can only guess it's either a difference in `session.name` or some evil auto-prepend file....

Comment: Yes, it's the exact same file, but /test/session.php has: $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'; at the end of it.

Comment: Do you have this online somewhere? I'm curious how the actual set-cookie header comes out at those urls....

Comment: Index Page: http://microgeek.me/ Session(Start session): http://microgeek.me/utils/session.php Session2(Check session): http://microgeek.me/utils/session2.php

Comment: Even more weird, I am re-coding my site, and my login on my old site(same site, older version) worked fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21034/discussion-between-wrikken-and-user1681891)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

Your code is checking for $_SESSION before starting a session.

Your session has to be started to bring $_SESSION to life.

Session data are stored either on the disk or in db based on how you are handling the sessions.

Every time you start a session the $_SESSION variable is created ... from the stored data.

Every time a php script execution is completed, the data in $_SESSION is serialized and written to the file or db ... and the variable is closed.

So unless you start a session there would be no $_SESSION.

```
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

This is appropriate

Comment: Sessions might be different if the url is varying ... like with and without www. (www.domain.com is different from domain.com) ... please check that also

Comment: No, I'm using the same url to test.

Comment: Is var_dump($_COOKIE) showing the same data relating to session id for all the three pages

Comment: Edifer 
The only cookie value is the session id, which is the the same.